# Exclude trailing newline when reading in skeleton file

Tags: autocmd, python

I have the following in my .vimrc:

`au BufNewFile *.py 0r ~/.vim/skeletons/py.skel | let IndentStyle = "python"`

However, when I open a new .py file, there is always a trailing empty line which I would like to remove. I thought it might be due to the final newline in the file `py.skel`, but I've chomped that off and the behavior persists.

How can I modify the autocommand to avoid this?

Comment: chain a `$delete` (or maybe `0delete`, I forget which). It's the behavior of `read`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:read` *inserts* text from a given file. When you start with empty file, it already has one (virtual, empty) line.

So if you do `:0read` then the text is *added* after 0th line (that is, *before* the first and only line), and then the former line #1 gets shifted to the end of file.

You can't prevent it, only to remove it. Personally, I'd prefer `:read filename | 1delete_` over `:0read filename | $delete_`, so the cursor finally goes to the first line, not to the last one.